# Posting alternative site recommendations as comments for closed questions

Tags: discussion, scope, immigration-questions, comments

I hate to send off a [soon-to-be] expat empty-handed; since there's currently no StackExchange site for expats ([obligatory link to expats proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates?referrer=pHo7j1-e9Kt9c2qQO4fLxA2)), I've taken to leaving comments on immigration questions offering alternative places that I have used to find answers in the past that the OP might consider helpful.

Examples:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/technology-oriented-travel-professional#comment11452_8652
- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8595/how-to-move-a-couple-of-boxes-over-the-ocean#comment-11365

Is this OK, or should I not be posting these comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally fine.  I possibly should have considered doing so on the TOTP one.  And if the expat proposal DOES take off, that'll be brilliant for us to send people to.

Comment: I got tired of waiting and [started my own](http://expats.askbot.com) (:

Comment: I know nothing about askbot - is it a stackexchange clone, or does it use the same software?

Comment: It's a clone; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/164291 (and more importantly http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5558/164291).

Comment: @todofixthis your own site doesn't exist anymore, this is an advantage of SE sites over concurrence